# How publish sharepoint web app

Tags: sharepoint-online

I made an App for Sharepoint and is working, tested in the area / DEV. What I need is to know how to install some other sharepoint site where I am administrator.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up a **Sharepoint App Catalog** or publish your app to the **public app store**.
Take a look to these links:
[Manage the App Catalog in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161234(v=office.15).aspx)
[Set up an app catalog on SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123530(v=office.15).aspx)
[Publish apps for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164070(v=office.15).aspx)